# How to delete only a fragment of sprite in unity (not mesh)?

Tags: unity

I am building a dash effect in unity and I am able to. But when dashing I want to destroy every "particle" in my dashing way. This "particle" I mention is not a whole gameObject but only a fragment of a gameObject that my gameObject can touch. For instance: If my character is 10 cm tall and the gameObject obstacle is 20 cm, I want only the 10 cm to destroy which my character touches.

I have seen a couple of tutorial videos but I am only able to see the tutorial for meshes and 3D objects but not 2D sprites. So, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Hint: Sprites are drawn as meshes. You can apply the same shader techniques you'd use on a mesh to a SpriteRenderer's material too.

Comment: @DMGregory, Can you please direct me to some documentation or videos to refer to. I have somewhat knowledge of meshes but I absolutely have no idea how  to approach this problem.

Comment: How would you approach it with a mesh?

Comment: I don't know. If it is a mesh, when colliding, I'd take my head and feet vectors to refer to that particular area of mesh(a square or rectangle) and destroy it. But, it may not be possible. I have another idea too. How about I create a sprite Mask so that when colliding sprite Mask comes into effect and collided part turns into the mask(which is background of my game). I have another idea too. Since, I don't know how to approach this problem, I will set my game in such a way that the player will only collide in a certain area of collider and that will make this whole thing easier.

Comment: Your mask solution sounds like it would work. How have you tried putting it into practice so far?

Comment: No, since, I have never used a mask. But, since you are emphasizing it, I will definitely give it a go. BTW, why am I not getting any other response in this question. By now, I should have some down-votes, if this was a silly question. Do I need to change the qn?

Comment: Questions that show an attempt to solve the problem, image examples, etc. tend to attract more attention. When you state just a rough intention, but show no work, you're putting a lot of work on folks who try to answer, since they have to produce a complete solution from nothing - not even a starting point to build on. That can often intimidate folks into not answering, or putting it off until the weekend when they have more time.